# Physical Server Requirements

Tags: server

I need some guidance. We want to set up a game server. It will be a physical server and then running the game servers as VMs. Now we need to know what the actual hardware for the physical server need to be to run the VMs. For an example, say we want to run 1000 Rust servers on the server, how would one calculate the requirements for the physical server.

Only been searching online for answers to this question without any luck.

Comment: I have not done the research to write a full answer. However, I did find [this](https://www.ovhcloud.com/en/bare-metal/game/rust-server/) : "To work properly, a Rust server requires at least 4GB of RAM. However, we recommend 8GB of RAM to get the ultimate gameplay experience." - You aren't going to have enough RAM on one server to run 1000 Rust servers, let alone adding in VMs. Are you sure you want to go the physical route? Or was 1000 an over estimate of how many servers you'd be running?

Comment: @Andy, Yes I agree with the amount of VMs wont be possible on one machine. Do you perhaps have a way to calculate what the hardware requirements would be of the physical server to run one of those Rust servers as a VM on the physical machine?

Answer (score 0):

Do a search on YouTube for running Rust Server on VM sites (I checked and there are a few), Test run Rust a online vm site, and that I would imagine give you a bit better idea as to how much physical hardware you might need, it will also give you an opportunity to spin up multiple Rust VM servers and see how you can expand it,and what limits you might hit, and how much hardware you might need. Sorry it's not a definitive answer, But maybe it's a suitable work around to test,and obtain an answer,then you can be the expert due to as you said "you can't find a answer to your searching".